# Spring Boot, property of type Path read from application.yaml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

I hope somebody will be able to help me with the following issue I find in Spring Boot version 2.3.5.

I have simple test application (cannot share sources) where:

- I have a class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")` and one field `private Path path`.
- `application.yaml` file has configured value `path: C:\\Local`

During application startup, the value of the property configured in `application.yaml` should print to console.
So I have the following behaviour:

- When I run the application from IntelliJ (Windows machine) it is running properly
- When I build the fat jar (with Maven Spring Boot plugin) and run the application, it fails with

```
Property: app.path
Value: C:\\Local
Origin: class path resource [application.yaml]:2:9
Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.nio.file.Path]
```

- When the same jar is run under Linux, having configured Linux path, it is working properly.

Any ideas why so? Or having a reference to a documentation related to the subject?

**Edit**
Class where property print happen:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationBootstrap implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired private ApplicationProperties properties;

    @Override public void run(final ApplicationArguments args) {
        System.out.println(properties.getPath());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationBootstrap.class);
    }
}
```

**Update**
So looks like the problem is in Classpath Loader.

The issue appear in `org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.PathEditor` on line 100.

```
else if (!resource.exists() && nioPathCandidate)
```

When running under IntellJ, the `ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader` is used, this one can resolve the value `C:\\Local`.

While running from jar, the `LaunchedURLClassLoader` is used and this fails when executing line 100 with same value, the exception message `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name`

So most probably the issue is in Spring Boot Class Loader.

**Update**

Issue appear in method `findResource()` from `LaunchedURLClassLoader` which delegate to same method to `URLClassLoader` while the `AppClassLoader` (which used when running from IntellJ) delegates to same method from `BuiltinClassLoader`.

**Final Answer**
The problem is that at some point it considers `c:` as protocol and it fails with an exception.

So the proper configuration in properties file should be: `app.path=file:C:\\Local`

**Related issues:**
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7161

Thank you.

Comment: Does IDEA use the same system-wide JRE that is used when you launch FatJar from CLI, or they are different?

Comment: Is the same JDK

Answer (score 1):

First of all your extension of application file should be "yml".
Can you please provide your application.yml properties?
The following example works for me:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class TestConfig {
  private Path path;

  public Path getPath() {
    return path;
  }

  public void setPath(Path path) {
    this.path = path;
  }
}
```

And applicaion.yml

```
app:
  path: C:\FOO\BAR
```

Comment: Thank you for ".yaml", it was a mistake, I fixed it, but still get same issue.

The properties class looks the same as yours and ```application.yml``` too.

Comment: Can you please provide the class where you try to print value in the console?

Comment: Updated question with the class.

Comment: Do you use the following import in ApplicationProperties class:
import java.nio.file.Path; 
?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: The Zulu OpenJDK 8

Comment: Can you please take a look to my repository?
https://github.com/SolukAndrian/stackoverflow application that created works for me. Can you please try to clone on your local machine and try to run?

Comment: The difference in your code and mine is the boot starter. In my case it was `spring-boot-starter` and in your app is `spring-boot-starter-web`. If I change in my project the starter to be `web` then it is working properly.
I removed `web` from your project and it failed.

Still the issue is strange, because why it would work properly if it is executed from IntelliJ.

Comment: I changed to spring-boot-starter.
And it still works for me

Comment: ensure that you reimported Maven. I just tried your project on personal laptop and get same issue. I will record a video and publish to youtube today/tomorrow.